Is the Google ML kit migrated from Firebase now free?
I am using Text Recognition v2 from ML Kit.
If I use the bundled library of Text Recognition v2, are there any usage restrictions?
I can't find information about pricing anywhere on the ML Kit page, so I'm leaving a question.
Here's pages that I refered:

https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/mobile-vision-migration
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/v2/android

Thank you.
I think it's free to use, because it is a library for on-device.
Before it is migrated, we should pay for it as we use it.
But now, it'is working even there's no internet. Because it is on device.

There's no charge while using MLKit SDK.
